# Replace "+" in a csv file using VBScript

Tags: regex, replace, vbscript

I'm looking to replace the symbol `+` in a CSV file. I'm using a VBScript run by another software.

I'm facing the error message "unexpected quantifier" 800A139A. However, the search and replace of `#` and `e` is working, and when I replace the research of `+` by research of `-`, it works. What could be the error?

```vb
Dim FILE1
Dim InFileName
Dim re
Dim reE
Dim reP

Set re = New RegExp
Set reE = New RegExp
Set reP = new RegExp
re.Pattern = "#"
reE.Pattern = "e"
reP.Pattern = "+"

re.Global = True
reE.Global = True
reP.Global = True

'Replace path and filename as required
'InFilename = "C:\" & Evoware.GetStringVariable("filename")
Set FILE1 = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set infile = FILE1.OpenTextFile(InFileName, 1, False)

strg = infile.ReadAll
infile.Close

strg = re.Replace(strg, "")
strg = reE.Replace(strg, "")
strg = reP.Replace(strg, "")

MsgBox(strg)
Set Outfile = File1.CreateTextFile(inFileName, 1, False)
Outfile.Write(strg)
```

Comment: Why use a regex? Use `Replace(str, what, with)`. Btw, when a `+` must be used in a regex, it must be escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm facing the error message "unexpected quantifier"

That is because the `+` symbol in regex represents a Greedy Quantifier. Which means one or more occurrences of the previous character/group. Example: `a+` should match: `a`, `aa`, `aaa`...

If you want to use `+` as a literal character, your term should be escaped with a backslash.

To do that, simply replace `"+"` to `"\+"`:

```
reP.Pattern = "\+"
```